# Confidence in pan-sharpened classification?

Tags: landsat, erdas-imagine, land-classification

I pan-sharpened one Landsat Image on ERDAS using the resolution merge resource, with brovey transform and nearest neighbor techniques. But I was told that in terms of land-use classification, it would be a mistake doing it, since pan-sharpening creates false pixels that would add erros.

Is that true?

Comment: Yes. Use the original for classification, the pan sharpened is just for display purposes.

Comment: There are many studies that do use pan-sharpened images as an input to be classified.

Answer (score 6):

In general, there are two approaches to classification: pixel-based and object-based:

**Pixel-based**: Each spatial pixel is evaluated by itself against a set classification parameters. In this case, pansharpening the image will not help you at all.

**Object-based / Segmentation**: In this approach pixels are evaluated as groups and segmented into groups based on homogeneity (spectrally and textually). In this case, pansharpening is an option, but the panchromatic band can also just be used along with the other optical bands.